# why is function returning a different thing when called alone VS when called twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, memory

so i have a recursive function that i call 2 times with different arguments but the second time i call it, it doesnt give the correct result, it only gives the correct result when i call it the first time not the second time. Maybe a memoy or cache issue ?

```
def m(n):
    s= [int(char) for char in str(n)]
    product = 1
    for x in s:
       product *= x
    return product
i = 0
def persistence(n):
    global i
   
    if len(str(n)) == 1:
       return i
    else:
        j = m(n)
        i+=1
        s = persistence(j)
        return s 



print(persistence(39)) 
print(persistence(4)) #returns 3 when called with the top one but 0 when called alone
```

Comment: That's because you are using i as a global variable. When you execute persistence again, the i variable value is not 0

Comment: `presistence(4)` will return `i` in the `if` branch. If it is the first time `persistence` has been called, then `i` is `0`. If you call it with `39` first, that call goes to the `else` branch, which changes the `i` variable. It will no longer be `0` when you call it with `4`. This is why you should avoid global, mutable state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a condiction `len(str(n))` in your function persistence, so that if `n` is a number between 0 and 9, you return `global i`.

When you call `print(persistence(4))` alone, your function return `global i` (equal to 0).

When you call `print(persistence(39))` first, and then `print(persistence(4))`, the first call set `global i` to 3, and the second call juste return the value value of `global i`, that as just been set to 3.

I don't really get what you want to do, but maybe your problem comes from the usage of `global`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using i as global variable. When you execute the method again, your i

```
def m(n):
    s= [int(char) for char in str(n)]
    product = 1
    for x in s:
       product *= x
    return product

def persistence_recursive(n, i):
    if len(str(n)) == 1:
       return i
    else:
        j = m(n)
        i+=1
        s = persistence_recursive(j, i)
        return s 

def persistence(n):
   return persistence_recursive(n, 0)



print(persistence(39)) # returns 3
print(persistence(4)) # returns 0
```